# Assembly registers in 64-bit architecture

Tags: assembly, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, cpu-registers, itanium

Following the [answer about assembly registers' sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15191217/2777359):

- First, what sizes are `eax`, `ax`, `ah` and their counterparts, in the 64-bit architecture? How to access a single register's byte and how to access all the 64-bit register's eight bytes?

  I'd love attention for both **x86-64 (x64)** and **Itanium** processors.
- Second, what is the correct way to use the four registers for holding the first four parameters in function calls in [the new calling convention](http://www.viva64.com/en/l/0001/#ID0E6GAE)?

Comment: hmm `eax == 32bits` `ax == 16bits` `ah|al == 8bits`, it's always like this, x64 adds new registers, back in the 16 bit days we only had `ax & al & ah` then when 32 bit addressing came round it was added in a way that didn't really effect how you address the 16bit or 8bit registers, the new registers in x64 (64 bit registers that overlap, eax that overlaps ax, etc) start with an `r` so `rax` `rbx` and so on. [see here](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo11.html) for more information.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

With the old names **all registers remain the same size**, just like when x86-16 was extended to x86-32. To access 64-bit integer registers you use the new names with [R-prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43933379/995714) such as *rax, rbx...*

Register names don't change so you just use the byte registers (a*l, bl, cl, dl, ah, bh, ch, dh*) for the LSB and MSB of *ax, bx, cx, dx* like before.  (*[How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191178/how-do-ax-ah-al-map-onto-eax)*)

There are also **8 new registers** called *r8-r15*. You can access their LSBs by adding the suffix `b` (or [`l` if you're using AMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43991779/995714)). For example *r8b, r9b, r10l, r11l...* You can also use the LSB of *esi, edi, esp, ebp* by the names *sil, dil, spl, bpl* with the new [REX prefix](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix), but you cannot use it at the same time with *ah, bh, ch or dh*.

Likewise the new registers' lowest word or double word can be accessed through the suffix `w` or `d`.  Writing a 32-bit register [zero-extends into the full 64-bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6), unlike writing low-8, high-8, or low-16 partial registers where the 8086 / 386 semantics still apply.

---

**Update:** Intel has just introduced a [new extension for x86-64](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html) called [APX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Performance_Extensions) which adds 16 more registers named r16-r31

So the list of general-purpose registers is like this:

| 64-bit register | Lower 32 bits | Lower 16 bits | Lower 8 bits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rax | eax | ax | al |
| rbx | ebx | bx | bl |
| rcx | ecx | cx | cl |
| rdx | edx | dx | dl |
| rsi | esi | si | sil |
| rdi | edi | di | dil |
| rbp | ebp | bp | bpl |
| rsp | esp | sp | spl |
| **r8** | r8d | r8w | r8b (r8l) |
| **r9** | r9d | r9w | r9b (r9l) |
| **r10** | r10d | r10w | r10b (r10l) |
| **r11** | r11d | r11w | r11b (r11l) |
| **r12** | r12d | r12w | r12b (r12l) |
| **r13** | r13d | r13w | r13b (r13l) |
| **r14** | r14d | r14w | r14b (r14l) |
| **r15** | r15d | r15w | r15b (r15l) |
| *r16 (with APX)* | r16d | r16w | r16b (r16l) |
| *r17 (with APX)* | r17d | r17w | r17b (r17l) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| *r31 (with APX)* | r31d | r31w | r31b (r31l) |

Of course there are also other types of registers like [control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#Control_registers_in_Intel_x86_series), [debug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register), [flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register), floating-point, vector, segment, test... registers. For more details check https://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Registers_x86. See also [What are the names of the new X86_64 processors registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1753627/995714)

---

#### Calling conventions

Regarding the *calling convention*, on each specific system there's **only one convention**<sup>1</sup>.  Follow the links for details on which integer and vector registers are [call-clobbered vs. call-preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers), and additional details like 16-byte alignment of RSP before a `call`, and quirks for variadic functions.

- [**On Windows**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x64-architecture):

  - RCX, RDX, R8, R9 for the first four arguments if they're integer or pointer
  - XMM0, XMM1, XMM2, XMM3 for floating-point arguments
  - The caller reserves 32 bytes of "shadow space" above the return address.  (If there are any stack args, they go above the shadow space.)

  <sup>1</sup>Since MSVC 2013 there's also a **new extended convention** on Windows called [`__vectorcall`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-vector-calling-convention/) so the "single convention policy" is not true anymore.
- **On Linux and other systems** that follow the [System V AMD64 ABI](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI), more arguments can be passed in registers and there's a 128-byte [red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) below the stack which may make leaf functions faster.

  - The first six integer or pointer arguments are passed in registers RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, and R9
  - Floating-point arguments are passed in XMM0 through XMM7

For more information should read [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) and [x86-64 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions)

There's also a convention used in [**Plan 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs) where

> - All registers are caller-saved
> - All parameters are passed on the stack
> - Return values are also returned on the stack, in space reserved below (stack-wise; higher addresses on amd64) the arguments.

[Golang follows the Plan 9 calling convention](https://go.dev/doc/asm), but since go 1.17+ they're gradually introducing a [register-based calling convention](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40724) for better performance. The calling convention can change in the future, and the compiler can generate stubs to automatically call assembly functions in older conventions. At the moment [the ABI specifies that](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/dev.regabi/src/cmd/compile/internal-abi.md)

- 9 general-purpose registers will be used to pass integer arguments: RAX, RBX, RCX, RDI, RSI, R8, R9, R10, R11
- 15 registers XMM0-XMM14 are used for floating-point arguments

<sub>In fact Plan 9 was always a weirdo. For example it forces a register to be 0 on RISC architectures without a hardware zero register. x86 register names on it are also consistent across 16, 32 and 64-bit x86 architectures with operand size indicated by mnemonic suffix. That means ax can be a 16, 32 or 64-bit register depending on the instruction suffix. If you're curious about it read</sub>

- <sub>[A Manual for the Plan 9 assembler](https://9p.io/sys/doc/asm.html)</sub>
- <sub>[Go/plan9’s assembler is weird](https://nelhagedebugsshit.tumblr.com/post/84342207533/things-i-learned-writing-a-jit-in-go)</sub>

---

OTOH [Itanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64) is a **completely different architecture** and has no relation to x86-64 whatsoever. It's a pure 64-bit architecture so all normal registers are 64-bit, no 32-bit or smaller version is available. There are a lot of registers in it:

> - 128 general-purpose integer registers r0 through r127, each carrying 64 value bits and a trap bit. We'll learn more about the trap bit later.
> - 128 floating point registers f0 through f127.
> - 64 predicate registers p0 through p63.
> - 8 branch registers b0 through b7.
> - An instruction pointer, which the Windows debugging engine for some reason calls iip. (The extra "i" is for "insane"?)
> - 128 special-purpose registers, not all of which have been given meanings. These are called "application registers" (ar) for some reason. I will cover selected register as they arise during the discussion.
> - Other miscellaneous registers we will not cover in this series.
>
> [The Itanium processor, part 1: Warming up](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=90821)

Read more on [What is the difference between x64 and IA-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11893364/995714)