# Load an address location to register using memory addressing modes in x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

I am trying to load a pointer into the %rdi register. The memory address I want is stored 10 bytes past the memory location of $rsp.

How would I write the assembly code for this? This is what I have so far

```
movq 10(%rsp),%rdi
ret
```

Comment: For historical reasons, while IA-32 <-> x86, IA-64 has nothing to do with x64/AMD64/x86-64 or however you want to call it (just don't call it IA-64 because that's Itanium)

Comment: Unless is *is* ia64..  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11893420/3437608

Comment: @cullub: I bet you 10000$ that this is not an IA-64 question, because x86-64 has `%rsp` and `%rdi` registers, while IA-64 doesn't.

Comment: @Peter it looks like the OP just edited, so I guess you're right...

Comment: Yes my bad, it's x86-64 instruction set

Comment: Can you explain what you really want. The instruction in the post is a LOAD instruction, in loads the *data* from the memory location %rsp+10 into register %rdi. Is that what you need?

Comment: Avoid the word "store" when you're not talking about writing to memory.  You just want RDI = RSP+10, right?  BTW, I may have been hasty in closing as a duplicate.  The target question is asking about exactly the instruction you need, with the same offset from the stack pointer, but neither the Q nor A exactly explain why it solves your problem.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614972/how-does-the-lea-instruction-interact-with-esp/21617964#21617964

Comment: I have a memory address stored in a location starting 10 bytes after the memory location of %rsp. I want to move this memory address to the %rdi register.

Comment: Are you sure you mean 10, and not `0x10`?  Otherwise IDK why you're asking a question, because the code in your question does load 8 bytes from RSP+10 into RDI.  I thought it was unusual that you wanted an unaligned address, but I figured you wanted to use RDI as a buffer for storing characters or something.  It would be even more unusual to load 8 bytes from an unaligned address, so I think you probably do mean `0x10` (i.e. 16)

Answer (score 1):

Try leaq instruction, it is often used to compute address offset, or a simple multiply–add computation like this:

```
leaq 4(%rsi,%rdi,2), %rdx    # rdx = 4 + rsi + (rdi << 1)
```

So what you need would be

```
leaq 0xa(%rsp),%rdi # assume you need an offset of decimal number 10
ret
```